# Handling read timeout on multiplexed sockets in *nix

Tags: c, sockets, callback

I'm trying to write a program that should poll about 3 to 4 hundred servers at one run each 10 minutes.

ust send an HTTP request and get a respond, parse it and store in DB. Now I have a C source code that actually do the job perfectly except that there are always some servers that do behave bad and block poller. I found some useful example that shows how to do what I need with multiplexed non-blocking sockets, select and callbacks.

So, what it does:

1. open socket in non-blocking mode:

```
recstate sckt_open(int *socketfd, const char *address, unsigned int *port)
{
  struct hostent *desthost;

  *socketfd = -1;

  desthost = gethostbyname(address); // get IP address of the destanation host by DNS name or IP
  if (!desthost || desthost->h_length != sizeof(struct in_addr))
  {
    if (verbose >= 2)
      fprintf(stderr, "sckt_open(): cannot resolve %s: unknown host\n",
          address);

    return (FAILED);
  }

  *socketfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // create an AF_INET stream socket
  if (*socketfd < 0)
  {
    if (verbose >= 2)
      fprintf(stderr, "sckt_open(): failed to create socket for %s:%d", address,
          *port);

    return (INTERROR);        // internal error occurred while processing record
  }

  int rc;
  if ((rc = fcntl(*socketfd, F_GETFL)) < 0
      || fcntl(*socketfd, F_SETFL, rc | O_NONBLOCK) < 0)
  {
    if (verbose >= 2)
      fprintf(stderr,
          "sckt_open(): failed to set nonblocking mode for socket %d for %s:%d",
          *socketfd, address, *port);

    return (INTERROR);        // internal error occurred while processing record
  }
  rc = 1;
  if (setsockopt(*socketfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (void *) &rc, sizeof(rc))
      < 0)
  {
    if (verbose >= 2)
      fprintf(stderr,
          "sckt_open(): failed set keepaliv mode for socket %d for %s:%d",
          *socketfd, address, *port);

    return (INTERROR);        // internal error occurred while processing record
  }

  //FIXME
  //    struct timeval timeout;      
  //    timeout.tv_sec = 10;
  //    timeout.tv_usec = 0;
  //    setsockopt(*socketfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (struct timeval *)&timeout, sizeof(struct timeval));

  struct sockaddr_in connaddr;
  memset(&connaddr, 0, sizeof(connaddr));
  connaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;                             // set proto family
  connaddr.sin_addr = *(struct in_addr *) desthost->h_addr; // set real destination address
  connaddr.sin_port = htons(*port);                      // set destination port

  if (connect(*socketfd, (struct sockaddr *) &connaddr, sizeof(connaddr)) < 0
      && errno != EINPROGRESS)
  {
    if (verbose >= 2)
      fprintf(stderr, "sckt_open(): socket %d: failed to connect to %s:%d",
          *socketfd, address, *port);

    return (FAILED);
  }

  if (verbose >= 2)
    printf("sckt_open(): created socket endpoint %d for %s:%d\n", *socketfd,
        address, *port);

  return (ACTIVE);
}
```

In case of ACTIVE, main loop will upload output buffer and then register a write callback. The write callback function will attempt to actually write a buffer to the socket and test the result: if write return smth. less then 0 but not EAGAIN it will remove all callbacks corresponding to this fd and mark server as FAILED, in case write returns smth. grater then 0, but less then length of output buffer it will return while kipping write callback active (partial write). If write returns with buffer length: it will now remove write callback and register read callback and return.

The read callback will figure out the OS input buffer size by calling ioctl with FIONREAD for the corresponding socket and then try to read that amount of bytes from socket to the local buffer. If no local buffer allocated and read returns 0, then read callback will close socket, report "0 bytes respond" and mark server as FAILED, if smth grater then 0 returned by read request, read callback will load data to the local buffer and return while keeping read callback active. If <0 returned by read request but errno is EAGAIN it will return, otherway will remove callback, close socket and mark server as FAILED. In case 0 return and nonempty local buffer, read callback will mark server as FINISHED, remove read callback, close socket and return.

There is another important thins: the way I check for sockets ready and callbacks need to be fired:

```
void sckt_cb_check(void)
{
  fd_set tread_fds, twrite_fds;
  int counter, ready_fds;

  tread_fds = read_fds;
  twrite_fds = write_fds;

  ready_fds = select(FD_MAX, &tread_fds, &twrite_fds, NULL, NULL); // check for how many file descriptors are ready

  if (ready_fds < 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "sckt_cb_check(): select returned an error: %s\n",
        strerror(errno));

    return;
  }

  for (counter = 0; ready_fds && counter < FD_MAX; counter++)
  {
    if (FD_ISSET(counter, &tread_fds))
    {
      ready_fds--;

      if (FD_ISSET(counter, &read_fds))
        read_callback[counter].callback_func(
            read_callback[counter].callback_arg);
    }

    if (FD_ISSET(counter, &twrite_fds))
    {
      ready_fds--;

      if (FD_ISSET(counter, &write_fds))
        write_callback[counter].callback_func(
            write_callback[counter].callback_arg);
    }
  }
}
```

And this is how callbacks are registered and removed:

```
void sckt_cb_add(int socketfd, scktop operation, void (*func), void *arg)
{
  struct callback *curr_callback;

  if (socketfd < 0 || socketfd > FD_MAX)
  {
    fprintf(stderr,
        "sckt_cb_add(): invalid file descriptor, failed to add new callback\n");

    return;
  }

  curr_callback =
      &(operation == WRITE ? write_callback : read_callback)[socketfd];
  curr_callback->callback_func = func;
  curr_callback->callback_arg = arg;
  FD_SET(socketfd, operation == WRITE ? &write_fds : &read_fds);

  if (verbose >= 2)
    printf("sckt_cb_add(): registered %s callback for socket fd %d\n",
        operation == WRITE ? "write" : "read", socketfd);
}

void sckt_cb_free(int socketfd, scktop operation)
{
  if (socketfd <= 0 || socketfd > FD_MAX)
  {
    fprintf(stderr,
        "sckt_cb_free(): invalid file descriptor, failed to free callback\n");

    return;
  }

  FD_CLR(socketfd, operation == WRITE ? &write_fds : &read_fds);

  if (verbose >= 2)
    printf("sckt_cb_free(): removed %s callback for socket fd: %d\n",
        operation == WRITE ? "write" : "read", socketfd);
}
```

Besides, there is an activeconnection counter, each time I get socket opened, I increment it, each time socket is closed die to any reason, I decrement it. The program will loop until this counter is 0, meaning all connection are closed anyway. So, when this mechanism try to poll this dummy server, it will never got socket closed, I tested to set socket timeout and select time out. Non of them did the job, socket remains opened and there is no way to figure out the time out condition (no read neither select returned with error). I do understand that there is a solution. Finally, I can add timer to the polling loop where I execute sckt_cb_check() and drop all this servers from that point after some time, but I don't think it's a good idea.

So, I found that there mast be a way to use pselect, set time out and indicate EINTR errno, but I have no Idea how to wire it all together.

UPD: Actually, it will stay in sckt_cd_check() forever in case of dummy server found. That makes my solution with timer in main loop useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, got per-server timeaouts working by adding a separate field for timestamp and select() timeout for checking all active polling queue.